# TYPO3 BE Login after few second Logout?

Tags: networking, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have used TYPO3 version 8.7.9 and i face a problems in BE login. When i login in BE a few second it's logout.

i can't determine this problems. it's network problems or TYPO3?

If notwork problems then how can i resolved this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a cookiedomain in the TYPO3 install tool? If not, try to set one.

Answer (score 0):

the login is done by a session cookie. the session cookie depends on some parameter, one of these is the IP. Your error description reminds to problems which occur if the internet connection is done by a variety of lines and each line has it's own IP (loadbalancer, reverse proxy, ...).
Try to widen the IP mask  or set `[BE][lockIP]= 0` at all (be aware you are loosing one security point)

Answer (score 0):

Put below lines in your AdditionalConfiguration.php.

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['lockIP'] = 3;` (and scale down till zero)

see [further details](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SecurityGuide/GuidelinesIntegrators/GlobalTypo3Options/Index.html#lockip)

This Problem occurs on a few TYPO3 8.7.8 and 8.7.9 instances we use, not sure why, since the public IP does not change at all - but scaling down the IP locking seems to work.